# removing negative labels alone from a plot (ggplot + R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot creating using `ggplot2` as shown [here](http://cl.ly/0t2C2j1S1U0m331D1I2g).

[image: Screen Shot 2012-03-02 at 10.02.08 AM.jpg]

The y-axis (coverage) can not be less than 0. However, since I draw the curve below, I get this negative value. Is it possible to remove negative labels in `ggplot2`? Or is it possible to get the red boxes with the y-axis in 1 layer and then draw the curves as a 2nd layer without labels?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `scale_y_continuous()` call, you can set the `breaks` argument manually. In your case, to something like `breaks=seq(0,100,20)`.